# Switch button changing state when scrolling in listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm a beginner in Android development. This problem happens when I am vertically scrolling in this listview. Switch button changes the state automatically. How do I solve this issue? The code is shown below:

```
public class TrainerSessionAdapterView extends BaseAdapter {
public TrainerSessionAdapterView(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    workoutList = new ArrayList<>();
    newSessionList = new ArrayList<>();
    type = context.getResources().getString(R.string.type);
    other = context.getResources().getString(R.string.other);
    objectID = context.getResources().getString(R.string.object_id);
}

   @Override
    public int getCount() {
    if (workoutList.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return workoutList.size();
    }

}


@Override
public ParseObject getItem(int position) {
    return workoutList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    removeSession = new ArrayList<String>();
    trainerWorkoutList =  (ArrayList<String>)user.get("trainer_workout_type");
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.session_listview, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (!workoutList.isEmpty() && position < workoutList.size() && change)  {
            ParseObject workoutObject = workoutList.get(position);
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(workoutObject.get(type).toString()));
            holder.sessionTypeView.setText(workoutObject.get(type).toString());
            if(trainerWorkoutList!=null && workoutObject.getObjectId()!=null){
                if (trainerWorkoutList.contains(workoutObject.getObjectId())){
                    holder.sessionSwitch.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
            else{
                holder.sessionSwitch.setChecked(false);
            }
        }  
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Please give more details with the code when posting. Not commenting out code as a workaround to the minimum character requirement isn't allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this,

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        removeSession = new ArrayList<String>();
        trainerWorkoutList =  (ArrayList<String>)user.get("trainer_workout_type");
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.session_listview, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.sessionSwitch.setChecked(false);

        if (!workoutList.isEmpty() && position < workoutList.size() && change)  {
                ParseObject workoutObject = workoutList.get(position);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(workoutObject.get(type).toString()));

                holder.sessionTypeView.setText(workoutObject.get(type).toString());

                if(trainerWorkoutList!=null && workoutObject.getObjectId()!=null){
                    if (trainerWorkoutList.contains(workoutObject.getObjectId())){
                        holder.sessionSwitch.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
            }  
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using the view holder pattern, your views are being reused.Hence witch is also being reused with different states than what you have intended for that row. Using Hades answer will change your switch back to false state and then if all criteria put if by your if loops are fulfilled then switch will be moved to true state.

Answer (score 1):

add this line in your getView method.

```
  holder.switch.setChecked(ArrayList.get(position).isStudentPresent());
```